# Can Google Analytics track URL previews generated by social media sites

Tags: google-analytics, facebook-opengraph, social-media, share-open-graph

When a link is posted to a social media site, such as Facebook, Twitter, and WhatsApp, does the preview that is generated lead to a page view that can be captured in Google Analytics? I'm assuming that each social media platform makes an HTTP call to the domain to get the Open Graph tags that it uses to create the preview.  A situation where I could foresee this behavior is if someone receives a link in an email and they simply copy the link and post it to social media. I'd love to be able to get a sense of whether that is happening.

If it does indeed generate a page view when the preview is first loaded, thenwhat happens if the post is forwarded/reshared on a platform? Would that action generate a new preview or reuse the existing preview?